# Выход из цикла PHP

Tags: php, циклы

Есть трехмерный массив.
Его обход осуществляется следующим способом:

```
foreach(){
    foreach(){
        foreach(){
            if (){
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Как мне сделать так, чтоб if отменял самый первый цикл?

Comment: `break 4;`  http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php

Comment: @rjhdby, а может 3, а не 4?

Comment: @rjhdby мне нужно отменить только первый цикл, чтоб остальные работали дальше

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: @Visman может. Вот всегда меня вымораживала эта несправедливость с `if` и `break`, тоже ведь вложенность.

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков что значит "_отменял самый первый цикл_"? вы можете либо выйти из цикла, либо перейти к следующей итерации.

Comment: помог break 2, @rjhdby запиши в ответ

Comment: Эдуард, "количество циклов" и "уровень вложенности циклов" -- это одно и то же. Вы путаете понятия "количество циклов" и "количество итераций", т.е. повторов в рамках текущего цикла.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, вы не хотите прерывать вложенные циклы. Не знаю с какой целью и что вы обходите, но предположу, что что-то ищите.

Можно сделать так:

```
foreach () { // 1
    $found = 0;

    foreach () { // 2
        foreach () { // 3
            if () {
                $found++;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($found > 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Но, может быть, лучше выделить метод:

```
function find() {
    $found = 0;
    foreach () { // 2
        foreach () {
            if () { // 3
                $found++;
            }
        }
    }

    return $found;
}

foreach () { // 1
    $found = find();
    if ($found > 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем смысл, если есть уже готовая команда для решения подобных костылей?

Comment: @nrjshka в некоторых случаях необходимо прервать не все циклы. Обычно это означает, что нужно провести декомпозицию.Чтобы вам было понятнее представьте такую задачу: есть список учеников; для каждого ученика есть список предметов, которые он изучает; по каждому предмету у ученика есть оценки; надо найти первого двоечника в списке, то есть такого ученика, у которого по одному предмету все оценки 2.

Comment: Опять же.Если нужно выйти из всех циклов - break без аргументов, если из 1, 2, 3, ... - break 1, break 2, break 3, ...

Comment: @nrjshka будте внимательны. break без указания аргумента выходит только из одного цикла, а не изо всех.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы **выйти** из **вложенных циклов** на PHP(for, foreach, while, do-while или switch) нужно использовать: `break *количество вложенных циклов, которые нужно прервать*;` 
Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
foreach(){
    foreach(){
        foreach(){
            if (){
              break 3;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Прочитать подробнее про break в PHP можно в [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php).

Comment: а разве в скобках оператора break() указывается  количество циклов, а не уровень вложенности?

Comment: @Эдуард `break принимает необязательный числовой аргумент, который сообщает ему выполнение какого количества вложенных структур необходимо прервать. Значение по умолчанию 1, только ближайшая структура будет прервана.` http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.break.php